How to Download the song from the music app in flutter
I have created music app using flutter now i want have a download function when i click on download icon then that song should and that song should store in my download folder
 Future<void> downloadMedia(String url) async {
  try {
    // Request permission to access storage
    var status = await Permission.storage.request();
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      // Handle permission denied
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Permission denied to access storage')),
      );
      return;
    }
     Directory? externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (externalDir == null) {
      // Handle if external storage directory is not available
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('External storage directory not available')),
      );
      return;
    }

    // Get the downloads directory

    // Create a Dio instance for making HTTP requests
    final dio = Dio();

    // Define the file path where the media will be downloaded
    final filePath = '${externalDir.path}/Download.mp3';

    // Start downloading the media file
    await dio.download(url, filePath, onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
      // Update download progress
      final progress = (received / total * 100).toInt();
      setState(() {
        downloadProgress = progress;
      });
    });

    // Show a message indicating successful download
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Media downloaded successfully')),
    );
    print('Downloaded file path: $filePath');

    // Open the downloaded file using OpenFile plugin
    //await OpenFile.open(filePath);
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle errors and log the error message
    print('Error downloading media: $e');
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Error downloading media: $e')),
    );
  }
}

this not working so help me some other code which is going to solve the problem
